# How to create TYPE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, ddl, user-defined-data-types

How do I create a datatype in plpgsql? I'm new to PostgreSQL, i'm converting oracle procedures into postgresql functions. They have created a type in oracle something like:

```
TYPE t_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Then declared & used it in the procedure like:

```
strings t_array;
strings(1) := lv_str;
```

I want to create `t_array type` in plpgsql and use it in functions, how can I create such type or is there any inbuilt type to achieve this functionality in plpgsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a type for that in PL/pgSQL, just declare an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) variable:

```
declare
  l_strings text[];
begin
  l_string[1] := 'This is the first string';
  l_string[2] := 'This is the second string';
end;
```

Arrays can be used as parameters as well:

```
create function do_something(p_some_number integer, p_strings text[])
  returns ..
as
...
```

Call it using `do_something(42, array['one', 'two'])`